# $q not waiting till the nested $http call completes

Tags: angularjs, http, q, angular-promise

I am using $q and checking whether all the $http.get service calls are completed. In one $http call, there is a nested $http.get call(which is being made in the success function). $q.allSettled is not waiting till the nested $http call completes. How to handle this scenario?

```
var promises = [];
var promise = $http.get(url1).success(function(data){
        $http.get(url2).success(function(data){
            console.log("success2");
        }).error(function(data){console.log("failue2")});
     })).error(function(data){
         console.log("failure1")
     });
promises.push(promise);

$q.allSettled(promises).then(function(data){
     console.log("log3");
});
```

I am using an improved version $q. Here is the code

```
angular.module("qImproved", [])
    .config(function($provide) {
        $provide.decorator("$q", function($delegate) {
            function allSettled(promises) {
                var deferred = $delegate.defer(),
                    counter = 0,
                    results = angular.isArray(promises) ? [] : {};

                angular.forEach(promises, function(promise, key) {
                    counter++;
                    $delegate.when(promise).then(function(value) {
                        if (results.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            return;
                        }
                        results[key] = {
                            status: "fulfilled",
                            value: value
                        };
                        if (!(--counter)) {
                            deferred.resolve(results);
                        }
                    }, function(reason) {
                        if (results.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            return;
                        }
                        results[key] = {
                            status: "rejected",
                            reason: reason
                        };
                        if (!(--counter)) {
                            deferred.resolve(results);
                        }
                    });
                });

                if (counter === 0) {
                    deferred.resolve(results);
                }

                return deferred.promise;
            }
            $delegate.allSettled = allSettled;
            return $delegate;
        });
    });
```

Comment: There is no `$q.allSettled` - there is `$q.all`. Angular's `$q` is not exactly the same as kriskowal's Q

Comment: `promisses` in `$q.allSettled` (which, as New Dev pointed out doesn't exist in AngularJS) is also misspelled in your code above

Comment: Sorry, I have attached the improved $q code which I am using. @mdewitt I have written a pseudo code.

Comment: Creating pseudo methods without mentioning it just adds to extra confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your promises array (although it is named plural) only contains one promise.

If you want to run those functions asynchronously then they need to be added the the promises array.

Or if you want to run them synchronously then don't just $q. Just put your callback code in the last `then/success`

#### Edit

You could use `$q.defer()` to create a new promise.
Add this promise to your promises array, and resolve it only in your final nested callback.

Then you will resolve when the chain of promises is compete, instead of only the first promise.

Comment: The array contains many promises. I have mentioned only one. I want to make sure all the promises and their nested promises in the array completes, then only print "log3"

Comment: Thanks. Can you please give the pseudo code? I am new to these promises.

Comment: No need of pseudo code. I was able to write it on my own. Thanks for the great help.